# C++ Virtual Memory Layout

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory-management, virtual-inheritance

#### Understanding Virtual Inheritance Memory Layouts

I am working towards a better understanding in resolved memory layouts that vTables and vPointers give us. I fully understand polymorphism and why it works and have really no trouble with it however there are a couple small things I seem to be tripping up on regarding **memory layouts** and understanding **virtual base offsets**. I know this stuff is not totally necessary in every day C++ code however it is an interest of mine, to get what is going on.

I have been referring to [this](http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance.html) site for some help understanding the memory layout that occurs as a result of using virtual inheritance.

In the **Virtual Inheritance** section of the page about half way down it offers visuals for the vTables generated, however I want to clarify the order in which I think several events take place:

[image]
<sub>(source: [phpcompiler.org](http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance/vtable2.png))</sub>

In the picture above, it seems to me that:

- We first include the vPtr that points to the `Left` vTable
- Next include any values unique to the `Left` class first (`Left::b`)
- Next, offsets are calculated so we can put any virtually inherited data directly after the data we just included. Size of vPtr + `int Left::b` = 8, so we offset `Top::a` by 8, and add that to the bottom of our layout.
- Rinse and repeat fort the Right class

[image]
<sub>(source: [phpcompiler.org](http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance/vtable3.png))</sub>

In *this* picture above, it seems to me that:

- We first include vPtr of first class we inherit from
- Since we are not *virtually* inheriting from that immediate base class, we can directly inherit any non-virtual data members specific to the class, without offsets i.e. (`Left::b`)
- We include vPtr of second class we inherit from
- Since we are not *virtually* inheriting from that immediate base class, we can directly inherit any non-virtual data members specific to the class, without offsets i.e. (`Right::c`)
- Next include any unique data to the `Bottom` class, `Bottom::d`
- Next we calculate offsets for the *virtual* data in our superclass's and include this at the bottom of our memory layout.
- Finally we are done with our memory layout for the `Bottom` class

To me, I think the above processes make sense in determining the memory layout in many cases, however I am wondering what happens if I change a few things.

1. How would the memory layout change if the `Bottom` virtually inherited from both `Left` and `Right`
2. Bottom inherits `Left` and `Right` regularly, but say `Right` defines its own `int a`, obviously this would make the `bottom.a` equal to whatever the `bottom.Right::a` is since its the most recently overrided, however where would this be placed in the memory layout?

I have a proposal layout for each of my questions (2) and would like to know if my thoughts behind them are correct, and if not, why...Thanks!

1.)

```
+--Bottom---+
| vPtrLeft  |
| vPtrRight |
| Bottom::d |
|  Left::b--+---From offset calculated by vPtr.Left in Bottom vTable
|  Right::b-+---From offset calculated by vPtr.Right in Bottom vTable
|  Top::a --+---From offsets calculated from vPtr.Left and vPtr.Right
+-----------+
```

- Include vPtr.Left, then look for any unique data to Left not inherited virtually (`None`) (i.e. do not require offsets)
- Include vPtr.Right, then look for any unique data to Right not inherited virtually (`None`) (i.e. do not require offsets)
- Add any data specific to this class, (`Bottom::d`)
- Acquire all virtual data requiring an offset from `Left`, then `Right` climbing up the chain of inheritance until we finish `Left` and `Right`'s virtually inherited `Top::a` attribute

2.)

```
+---Bottom---+
|  vPtrLeft  |
|  Left::b---+---inheriting normally from Left
|  vPtrRight +
|  Right::c--+---inheriting normally from Right
|  Right::a--+---inheriting normally from Right
|  Bottom::d |   also most recently overrided value for A
|  Top::a----+---From offsets calculated from vPtr.Left and vPtr.Right
+------------+
```

Looking for my feedback on the logic behind these layouts, thank you.

#### Edit:

I know this was marked as a duplicate but I believe that this question has more specifics involved with it than the other, and I am looking for some answers to variations on regular multiple virtual inheritance to understand Object Memory Layouts with Virtual Inheritance

Comment: Very nicely presented question (that in itself is surely an upvote), but, sadly is a duplicate.

Comment: @Bathsheba First, thank you Second, I understand the answer in the question that people are saying this is a dup of however I wish to ask a bit more than the other person did. I understand the basic order of the memory layout as far as object territory goes, but I want to know if virtually inherited (through virtual inheritance or virtual modifier) data takes a back seat to non virtual data. For example, in my question above, if I inherit Left and Right virtually, not just Top, this makes me wonder, does that mean Bottom::d will come before this Left::b and Right::c since they are now virtual?